# Increase bandwidth of Linksys WRT54GL (with Tomato inside)

Tags: bandwidth, performance-tuning, linksys, tomato, router

I have Linksys WRT54GL with Tomato firmware installed. When I connect internet cable directly to a computer I can download at about 8 MB/s, however when internet is access through the router maximum speed is up to 4 MB/s.

Statistics always show that there are about 3 MB of memory available, and CPU load does not exceeds 0.6. What else can be a bottleneck for the bandwidth.

EDIT: QoS is disabled.

Comment: Is QoS interfering? The cable guy was going mad wondering why my connection was only 6meg. Turned out I still had QoS settings for my DSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about 4MBytes/s, i'd say that this is near the max that a wrt54gl can handle.

Here is the result of a IxChariot test, with streams in both direction.

[image: ixchariot]

Note the avg speed of 36Mbps, which 4.5MB/s.